# Allow other remote access computer for browser only

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, teamviewer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit a user account to use only Internet Explorer (or Firefox) in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/309325/limit-a-user-account-to-use-only-internet-explorer-or-firefox-in-windows-7)

I have a computer of windows 7 professional and I wish to allow other to login the computer for the usage of browser only, and cannot view my personal information on the computer.

Is that a way for configuring it?

Comment: You've asked nearly the exact same question as well? http://superuser.com/questions/476525/how-to-create-user-account-that-only-allowed-to-access-the-web-browser

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible using teamviewer.

But you can use the Remote Desktop Connection tool and create a restricted account for your users.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/476525/how-to-create-user-account-that-only-allowed-to-access-the-web-browser

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have asked a question regarding how to achieve what have mentioned in your reply. Thanks.